# Why if (condition) don't work with '{""}''

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm setting up a PHP code that takes some infos from Bash and put them in PHP. My If statement don't sort what i write or get from bash.

This is for a Server Apache2 on Linux. I've tried to put my string that i want to use in my condition in a variable.

```
GameToken = `grep "Matching server game" "${FactorioServerLogPath}" 2> /dev/null | awk '{print $7}' | tail -1 | tail -c +2 | head -c -2`;

$GameState = `curl -s -X GET -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" "https://multiplayer.factorio.com/get-game-details/$GameToken"`;

if ( $GameState != '{"message":"no game for given game_id"}' ) {
  echo "<h2> The Server is up and running </h2>";
} else {
  echo "<h2> The Server is currently turned off </h2>";
}
```

The outpout should look like The Server is currently turned off when the variable $GameState is not like {"message":"no game for given game_id"}.

Comment: You can get the error message here for example [link](https://multiplayer.factorio.com/get-game-details/4213123123123123123)

Comment: And what have you tried to spot the error? What does `$GameState` contain after executing the code?

Comment: Is the missing `$` on `GameToken` just a typo? You should output the values of the two variables and make sure they are what you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you should first decode it then try to check with if condition:

forexample:

```
$arr = json_decode($GameState, true);

if(array_key_exists('message', $arr) && $arr['message'] == 'no game for given game_id'){
     //do what you want
}
```

or maybe much better to do it:

```
$arr = json_decode($GameState, true);

if(array_key_exists('message', $arr)){
    if($arr['message'] != 'no game for given game_id'){
        echo "<h2> The Server is up and running </h2>";
    }else{
        echo "<h2> The Server is currently turned off </h2>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh yes but will the array in this case take the { } in case too ?

Comment: using `json_decode($GameState, true);` it is not anymore string. so you can use it as array. With this you can access all parameters inside of array. Please check https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp if you are new in php.

Comment: and please submit answer if it helped you :)